# How to reset status in QUnit?

Tags: javascript, jquery, qunit

Is there a way of resetting QUnit tests without reloading the page ?

On the documentation it says that QUnit.init( ) reinitializes if it was already initialized, but this doesn't seem to work.
I get a message "Running..." where the result should be.

http://docs.jquery.com/QUnit

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wrap all your tests inside a function.

Call the function when you're ready for the test to run.

If you want to rerun the test after QUnit has finished, then make and call a function like 'rerunQUnitTest'.

```
var runAllTest = function(){
    test( "test 1", function(){
        var a = true;
        equal( a, true, "function a should return false" );
    });
};
// call rerunQUnitTest to reset and run your tests again.
var rerunQUnitTest = function(){
    QUnit.reset();  // should clear the DOM
    QUnit.init();   // resets the qunit test environment
    QUnit.start();  // allows for the new test to be captured.
    runAllTest();   // runs your functions that has all the test wrapped inside.
};
runAllTest();   // auto runs your tests.
```

Comment: Note that this answer is outdated if anyone finds their way here -- both `QUnit.reset()` and `Qunit.init()` no longer exist (for quite some time)